# How do I install modules for Python 3.6 using Pip3 in Linux Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, ubuntu-16.04

I am running Linux Ubuntu 16.04, and my default version of python3 is Python 3.5.2.

I downloaded Python 3.6 to have a more recent version of Python. I can get it running on my command line using 'python3.6', while my default version of python3 remains Python 3.5.2.

I want to install the packages I had on Python 3.5.2 in Python 3.6. I tried to use the following command:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

But I get the following message:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.18.5)
```

How do I get pip3 to install packages to Python 3.6 specifically?

This is my current version of pip3:

```
pip3 --version
pip 20.2.4 from /home/[username]/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `pip3.6` or `python3.6 -m pip`.

If both don't work, `pip` is not installed for the new Python version.
Follow the instructions at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ but make sure to use `python3.6` instead of just `python`!

On some installations it might be necessary to use `sudo` before `python`/`python3.6`.

Comment: `python3.6 -m pip install [package name]` works for me.

Neither `pip3.6` or `pip-3.6` (suggested by the previous comment) work. I'm not quite sure why that is, any suggestions?

Comment: Not in all cases the `pip3.6` script is installed. But in general it is advisable to use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) for development to separate the libraries for the projects. When you are in a virtual environment `pip` and `pip3` should both work as usual and manage the packages in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use an exact version, something like `pip-3.5.2` or `pip-3.6`